# On mouse down change class but revert it on mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i click on a class i want to remove the class and add a new class to the element. Now when i release the mouse from the class i want to remove the new class added and replace with the old class.

This is only adding the new class but is not reversing the change when i take the mouse of.

```
<i class="fa fa-arrows"></i>


    $('.fa-arrows').mousedown(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('fa-arrows').addClass('fa-random');
    });

    $('.fa-random').on('mouseup',function(){
        $(this).removeClass('fa-random').addClass('fa-arrows');
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/873k5pgg/

Comment: You fiddle link just takes to homepage. Perhaps you linked the wrong example?

Comment: aha , sorry this is the link https://jsfiddle.net/873k5pgg/

Comment: because the event is not bound automatically when you change the class! The mousdown should be chained to the arrows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a variable to be true/false if it is clicked or not. Script will need to be altered if you're doing this multiple times on the same page.

```js
var clicked = false;

$(document).on('mousedown', '.fa-arrows', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-arrows').addClass('fa-random');
    clicked = true;
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function(){
    if (clicked) {
        clicked = false;
     $('.fa-random').removeClass('fa-random').addClass('fa-arrows');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.fa-arrows', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-arrows').addClass('fa-random');
});
$(document).on('mouseup', '.fa-random', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-random').addClass('fa-arrows');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/873k5pgg/1/)**

Comment: How about if i let go of the mouse when i am not hovering on the icon. It does not work then. Is there anyway to capture this?

Comment: Change the mouse up to `).on('mouseup mouseout',`

Answer (score 3):

What your jQuery does when this code is executed is: it looks for all `.fa-arrows` and binds the function to `mousedown` and it looks for all `.fa-random` and binds the other function to `mouseup`. *This happens once*, it is not magically re-evaluated everytime any class/the DOM changes. (That is where React/AngularJS/... come into play.)

You either have to re-evaluate the binds manually whenever the classes change (in the bound functions), or bind both to the same elements (I'd go with the latter):

```js
$('.fa-arrows')
  .on('mousedown', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-arrows').addClass('fa-random');
  })
  .on('mouseup', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-random').addClass('fa-arrows');
  });
```

```css
.fa-arrows { text-decoration: underline; }
.fa-random { color: red; text-decoration: line-through; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="fa-arrows">mousedown me</p>
```

*Edit: that said, why not just use css?*

```css
p { text-decoration: underline }
p:active { color: red; text-decoration: line-through; }
```

```html
<p>mousedown me</p>
```

Comment: How about if i let go of the mouse when i am not hovering on the icon. It does not work then. Is there anyway to capture this?

Comment: jQuery has a [blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) event for that. You could bind one event handler to both `mouseup` and `blur`. But that would fire if you keep your mouse hold down and move it away from the element. If you really want to fire the mouseup event when the user moves the mouse away from the icon you have to use *centralized event handling* (capturing all events at the document, then dispatching them to the element that wants them) -- but this is a long and ugly road to go.

Comment: the pure-css version works when not hovering the icon, btw ;)

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is because the events are set at the start, and the mouseup event is set to `.fa-random` which doesn't exist at that moment.

Like j08691 said you can use event delegation from the document, or you could put the event ons `.fa` and it should work too:

```
$('.fa').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-arrows').addClass('fa-random');
});

$('.fa').mouseup(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-random').addClass('fa-arrows');
});
```

Comment: How about if i let go of the mouse when i am not hovering on the icon. It does not work then. Is there anyway to capture this?